# Is there a way to move the cell back to initial position after dragging it left/right some-bit and then releasing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have implemented left/right swiping for UITableViewCell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
       let closeAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Close", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view: UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        success(true)
    })

    closeAction.image = UIImage(named: "tick")
    closeAction.backgroundColor = .purple
    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [closeAction])

    return config
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Update", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view: UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")

        success(true)
    })

    modifyAction.image = UIImage(named: "hammer")
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
}
```

but cell remains on the last position when I release it after dragging some bit(even tough it moves back when I click it again ). Is there a way to move the cell back to initial position after dragging it some-bit and releasing? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want the revealed buttons to be hidden again?  If this is the case how do you expect the user to tap on them?

Comment: Yes exactly, the same functionality like lets say in gmail.
The user will not be able to click it, but instead he will be able to swipe little bit more and action will be executed(with no need to click it)

Comment: Sorry I've been looking into it and I can't see any way to do this with the standard functionality.  The only options I can see are to develop your own version (maybe using a scroll view) or to find a 3rd party one.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Yep couldn't find standard way neither. Yes the scroll view or  gesture recognizer are another options, but before starting using them just wanted to check if there is standard or easier way to do that (with no 3rd party libraries) :)